# Windows SetTimer() vs using SleepConditionVariableCS()

Tags: c++, windows

I currently have a timer implemented using tbb::condition_variable which under the covers uses native Windows call SleepConditionVariableCS() . One of my co-workers think that if I use Windows SetTimer() there would be a performance gain. My question is, is my co-worker's statement true?

Implementation details:
Main function: calls a callback function after the time-out value.
Additional functionality: the time-out value can be reset, should be able to stop the timer.

Following is the code I can use to implement the main functionality of the timer:

Using SetTimer():

```
void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND, UINT, UINT, DWORD); // this is the callback function
                                                  // it will set the j=0 in the while loop below

UINT id;
MSG msg;

id = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 3000, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);

// thread waits until j=0
while(j) {
GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

KillTimer(NULL, id);
```

Using SleepConditionVariableCS():

```
CRITICAL_SECTION CritSection;
CONDITION_VARIABLE ConditionVar;

EnterCriticalSection(&CritSection);

SleepConditionVariableCS(&ConditionVar, &CritSection, INFINITE);

//Here call the callback function.
```

Comment: `SetTimer` and `SleepConditionVariableCS` are very different. They are not really related to each other aside from the fact that they both involve time. `SetTimer` is a UI function that requires a message pump. It returns immediately. `SleepConditionVariableCS` is a non-UI function that does not pump messages. It does not return until the condition is met or the sleep times out.

Comment: I agree. I included some sample code above on how I think the main functionality can be achieved using both calls. Do they look ok?

Comment: Its really hard to compare those two methods. I wonder if you even could call killtimer from some other thread than where it was created.

Comment: One version pumps messages while waiting. The other doesn't. They are not equivalent. Also, the first version is not idiomatic. `SetTimer` is expected to be used in the asynchronous model, where you set a timer, then return. When the timer fires, you resume work.

Comment: Synchronicity doesn't really apply to my implementation since I create a new thread just for the Timer. So if I use `SetTimer()` that thread will use the CPU to pump messages whereas if I use `SleepConditionVariableCS()` the thread basically sleeps yielding for other threads?

Comment: You are getting all the overhead that's required to implement a message queue for the thread.  For no performance benefit.  CreateTimerQueueTimer is best but the callback is asynchronous.

Comment: I guess my question should be, under the hood are the mechanisms used by Windows to wake up a thread from SleepConditionVariableCS and wake up a thread from it's thread pool to do a callback when CreateTimerQueueTimer() is used are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your co-worker's statement is most likely (like, 99.99%) false.

1. Ask yourself is there a performance issue with the existing code? If yes, can your co-worker prove that the condition variable is the performance bottleneck? As in, did they run any benchmarks?
2. `SleepConditionVariableCS` is used for thread synchronization, while `SetTimer` is used to queue (small amount of) work asynchronously. They literally have nothing in common.
3. `TimerProc` is called from default window procedure so that means you need a window and a message pump.
4. If I am not mistaken, `TimerProc` is not meant for long background processing.
5. Any callback function called by a periodic timer must be [reentrant and thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) and guard any use of shared resources by using one of the many available thread synchronization primitives (such as mutexes, SRW locks, semaphores, critical sections, and condition variables).

TL;DR — unless thread synchronization is not necessary, you cannot replace condition variable with a timer callback.

Finally, depending on the amount of work done in the callback, either using the timer queue timers or waitable timers would be much better than using `SetTimer`.